A cardinal inequality for finiteness
Nearly ten years ago, I explained in a blog post that, assuming only ZF, a cardinal number $\mathfrak{n}$ is finite if and only if it satisfies this monstrous inequality:
$$2^{2^{2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}}} \lt \left(2^{2^{2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}}}\right)^2 = 4^{2^{2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}}}$$
Where "finite" is meant in the strictest Tarskian sense: in bijection with a finite ordinal.
My question is a bit vague since "simple" has a lot of interpretations but here it is:

Is there a simpler cardinal inequality that is equivalent to finiteness and uses only cardinal exponentiation?


Oh that's hideous, I love it!

I suspect 4 could be replaced by 3 but even that requires some serious work. I expect the answer to be negative in some sense but I don't know what that "sense" is.

Läuchli proved in 1961 that $\mathfrak{n}$ is finite if and only if $2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}＜2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}\cdot2$. As a consequence, $\mathfrak{n}$ is finite if and only if $2^{2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}}＜(2^{2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}})^2$. It is still open (asked by Läuchli) whether $\mathfrak{n}$ is finite if and only if $2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}＜(2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}})^2$.
Läuchli, H., Ein Beitrag zur Kardinalzahlarithmetik ohne Auswahlaxiom, Z. Math. Logik Grundlagen Math. 7, 141-145 (1961). ZBL0114.01005.
For an English translation of Läuchli's paper, see here.

I'm not sure I follow the second iff here. Could you explain?

@François The right hand side of the second iff implies the right hand side of the first iff.

I got lost in the stack of 2s... Thanks for pointing out Läuchli's question.

On my homepage, there is an English translation of Läuchli's paper.

Thank you so much for this wonderful answer and your translation of Läuchli's paper!
